# Small signal analysis common source

Tags: circuit-analysis, cmos

I'm trying to get the small signal model for this circuit:

[image]

This is my attempt
I'm not sure where W1 should go. Should it be shorting out RD? Also R2 = RD on this circuit diagram

[image]

Comment: EE.SE has a built-in circuit editor

Comment: The small signal model depends on the operating point of the circuit. Is M2 in saturation, threshold voltage, voltage drop across R2, ...